# nginx re-route all data based on header

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

We have a requirement for nginx proxy-pass, where :
if the header x-header=acme, re-route all he request to acme endpoint, if x-header=apple, re-route all request to apple endpoint. How do we achieve this  in nginx reverse-proxy and proxy-pass?